# Is there any way to change the Color in SetPixel thickness?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is the code i'm using:

```
e.FillEllipse(cloudColors[cloudColorIndex], pt.X * (float)currentFactor, pt.Y * (float)currentFactor, radius, radius);
bmp4.SetPixel((int)pt.X * (int)currentFactor, (int)pt.Y * (int)currentFactor, Color.Yellow);
bmp4.Save(@"c:\temp\yellowbmpcolor.jpg");
```

When i'm using FillEllipse there is a property to set the radius for example 2.0f,2.0f
But when i'm using SetPixel to save the pixels to the bmp4 there is no any property to set the Color.Yellow thickness.

Any solution for this ? I want that the pixels i set to the bmp4 will be in the same radius as they are in FillEllipse.

Comment: You need to post more code and context. SetPixel sets *a single pixel*. There is no radius. You can create graphics from the bitmap and then use FillElipse on that. Or you can do it yourself with a loop.

Comment: Thing is... `FillEllipse` doesn't have a radius either. I can imagine wanting to draw a point matching the pen of `DrawEllipse`, but `FillEllipse` doesn't *have* a pen, only a fill.

Comment: Radius in FillEllipse i mean Width and Height. So the point it draw can be Width 2.0f and Height 2.0f or any other float value. And when i set the pixels to bmp4 it dosen't set the same pixels(points) size of Width and Height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a Graphics object from the Bitmap and draw your ellipses on it:

```
Bitmap bm;

Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
etc
g.FillEllipse(....);
etc
g.Dispose();
```

More here [How to: Create Graphics Objects for Drawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y289054(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Getting Started with Graphics Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da0f23z7(v=vs.110).aspx%20Getting%20Started%20with%20Graphics%20Programming)